# How to flatten data in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

In Flux.jl, I have some data in one layer I want to convert to an 1-dimensional array so that I can input it to the next layer. Is there a built-in function to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flux provides a built in `Flux.flatten()` function which, [according to the Flux docs](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/layers/#Flux.flatten):

> Reshape arbitrarly-shaped input into a matrix-shaped output, preserving the size of the last dimension.

You can see an example of this as follows:

```
julia> rand(Int8, 3,4,2)  # batch of two matrices, each 3 x 4
3×4×2 Array{Int8, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 -29  -97  61    1
  34  -53   4  -16
  74   46  41  -40

[:, :, 2] =
  10    25  -86  77
  94   -48  114   1
 -68  -125   35  68

julia> Flux.flatten(ans)  # batch of two vectors
12×2 Matrix{Int8}:
 -29    10
  34    94
  74   -68
 -97    25
 -53   -48
  46  -125
  61   -86
   4   114
  41    35
   1    77
 -16     1
 -40    68
```

Comment: why would I keep getting the error `UndefVarError: flatten not defined`?

Comment: I suggest posting a separate question about this with what you are trying to do